# Not able to Find compatible version of embedded java version and gradle tools version for Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I tried with jdk 17 and 18 its giving me the same issue
[image]

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0.

Required by:
project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.0
project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.0

No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:

- Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
  - Other compatible attribute:

    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
- Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
  - Other compatible attributes:

    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
- Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
  - Other compatible attribute:

    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
- Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.0 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:

  - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
  - Other compatible attributes:

    - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
    - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
    - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

If anyone else also faced the same issue with android studio flamingo please suggest some solutions.

Comment: Android only supports upto java 11

Comment: Gradle between 7.6 and 8.0 supports Java <= 19, Gradle 8.1 supports Java <= 20.

Comment: the issue start after updating to android studio to flamingo

Comment: same problem found solution?

Comment: The same question can also be found here (with answer) https://stackoverflow.com/q/76137431/150978

Answer (score 2):

Change in Settings->Gradle Java JDK to 17 it maybe solves your problem

Comment: No still not working!!