# How to solve this issue for the Gradle build for the new Android Studio Flamingo

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-flamingo

I have upgraded the jdk version to 20. After doing that I have installed the latest version of Android from the website which is Android Studio Flamingo. But while performing the Gradle run it is showing:

> Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4-bin\c0gwcg53nkjbqw7r0h0umtfvt\gradle-7.4-bin.zip.lck

Comment: Upgrade JDK only if necessary. Most gradle versions (and the used plugins) are not compatible with every JDK, especially newer JDK versions make problems. Instead use the Android Studio integrated JDK (JDK 17 in FLamingo).

Comment: So should i reinstall the jdk 17 to resolve this issue?

Comment: If you have AS Flamingo installed then you always have the built-in JDK 17. Just change the gradle JDK in project settings.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/76138830/150978

Comment: You may need to show the whole of your stack trace in your message in your question. The error you have shown may be an error that is the result of another preceding error.

Comment: I am getting this error:
Multiple Gradle daemons might be spawned because the Gradle JDK and JAVA_HOME locations are different. Project 'NewCADViewerApp' is using the following JDK location when running Gradle: 'C:/Users/sanmo/.jdks/jbr-17.0.7' The system environment variable JAVA_HOME is: 'C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr' If you dont need to use different paths (or if JAVA_HOME is undefined), youcan avoid spawning multiple daemons by setting JAVA_HOME and the JDK locationto the same path. More info... Select the Gradle JDK location Do not show this warning again