# setting up cordova cli for android build from construct 2 project

Tags: java, cordova, gradle, cordova-cli, construct-2

I always find a problem when I want to build android application in cordova cli from project construct 2, can you guys help me to prepare my cordova cli properly(step by step), complete from the initial export of the project in cordova until it becomes an apk. I didn't find the right way when I searched the way on the YouTube platform

When I try `cordova build android` an error message appears:

```
C:\Users\USER\Documents\AdvDark>cordova build android
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions
ANDROID_HOME=C:\SDKLAGI (recommended setting)
ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=C:\SDKLAGI (DEPRECATED)
Using Android SDK: C:\SDKLAGI
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 2 incompatible and 1 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 24s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'Adventure In The Dark'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a runtime of a library compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '7.6' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares an API of a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a runtime of a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2 declares a runtime of a component, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '7.6')

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.

You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.

See https://docs.gradle.org/7.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 10s
Command failed with exit code 1: C:\Users\USER\Documents\AdvDark\platforms\android\gradlew -b C:\Users\USER\Documents\AdvDark\platforms\android\build.gradle cdvBuildDebug
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Looks like 7.4.2 is compatible with Java 11 or later, and you are using Java 8.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to build Java or Kotlin project in Android Studio after flamingo update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76137431/unable-to-build-java-or-kotlin-project-in-android-studio-after-flamingo-update)