# Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run error

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I'm encountering an error when running my Android project that says

> "An exception occurred applying plugin request [id:
> 'com.android.application']"

. The error message is as follows:

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'. Android
> Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java
> 12. Your current JDK is located in C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.2 You can try some of the following options:
>
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

Here is my project's Gradle configuration:

**Top-level build.gradle:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.0.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.8.20' apply false
}
```

**Module build.gradle:**

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.colorgame'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.colorgame"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

}
```

**gradle.properties:**

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
org.gradle.java.home=C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk-12.0.2
android.useAndroidX=true
kotlin.code.style=official
android.nonTransitiveRClass=true
```

How can I resolve this error? What changes do I need to make? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76137431/150978