# Android No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1

Tags: java, android, flutter, gradle

After upgrading the `Gradle` version and trying to run `gradlew clean` i get this error and i can't resolve that

```
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.
     Required by:
         project :
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8  
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
```

i read more documentation and issues about this problem and i try to change java version to `11`

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}
```

`distributionUrl`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.0-all.zip
```

and `gradle.properties`:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m
android.useAndroidX=true
android.enableJetifier=true
android.defaults.buildfeatures.buildconfig=true
android.nonTransitiveRClass=false
android.nonFinalResIds=false
```

Comment: AGP 8.x requires Java 17. You need to switch to Java 17.According to the error message you are using Java 8. Check the JDK configured for Gradle within Android Studio. There are multiple identical questions here on SO.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76137431/150978