# Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm running the most recent version of Android Studio (Giraffe). I created a new application and added a new module . Then I did nothing; I attempted to assemble the release but received this problem.

I tried fixing the problem by changing Gradle JDK to JDK 11 but still I am getting this error.

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.1.1
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.1.1
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8      
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.1.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
```

I even tried by adding this to my build.gradle

```
compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
```

But this couldn't help too. Help needed.

Comment: Latest Android Gradle tools require AFAIR Java 17. You can change JDK for Gradle in AS settings and user the built-in JDK. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76138830/150978

Comment: @Robert thankyou so much. It worked. How do i add your comment as solution.