# Android No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 was found

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle

After upgrading to the latest version of android studio Flamingo, I am having the following problem.

I also created an empty project from scratch, but it gives me problems.

The same problem is found here: [Not able to Find compatible version of embedded java version and gradle tools version for Android Studio Flamingo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76036154/not-able-to-find-compatible-version-of-embedded-java-version-and-gradle-tools-ve)

Can you give me a hand?

[image]

```
A problem occurred configuring root project 'My Application'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1.
     Required by:
         project : > com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.0.1
         project : > com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.0.1
      > No matching variant of com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally, as well as attribute 'org.gradle.plugin.api-version' with value '8.0' but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a library, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component for use during runtime, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability com.android.tools.build:gradle:8.0.1 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them packaged as a jar)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.gradle.plugin.api-version (required '8.0')

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
```